# Scanner's buffer not representative of entire file when newlines enabled

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Basically, what I'm doing is writing to a file and then reading it later. A few times I was looking at the buffer, and seeing lines 'cut off,' and getting concerned it was a flushing issue. However, I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336478/does-the-scanner-class-load-the-entire-file-into-memory-at-once), which states:

> So, it appears scanner does not read the entire file at once...it reads file by buffer - which means in chunks.

and I see that reflected in my scanner. Looking at the buffer size, I see 1024 as the size.

However! I was writing each entry as a separate line, passing in the message and appending `\n` to it before writing. Taking that `\n` away then results in something interesting. When running without the newlines, I find that the buffer size has magically increased to something interesting like 5,232, and I can now see the entire contents of the file in the buffer!

The way I make the Scanner is simply a `new Scanner(new FileInputStream("path.txt"))`, and then inspect it using Intellij's variable inspection (that's where I got the idea of cutting off from, I wasn't able to see everything in the file)

Essentially, my question is: why does adding the newlines force the buffer to be a fixed size and obey the rules, and not adding newlines (meaning the entire file is just one line) lets the buffer be whatever size it needs to be?

Comment: Can you please provide some code as to how are you creating the `Scanner`? are you using any regex or are you going `nextLine()` etc?

Comment: @ringbearer I create the scanner from a `FileInputStream` and then inspect it using Intellij's inspection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest, if you only want to read a file, to use the `BufferedReader` instead of a `Scanner`. See this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231369/scanner-vs-bufferedreader) for more information.

To answer your question: 
You're right, the default Scanner buffer size is 1024 ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341345/does-a-java-scanner-implicitly-create-a-buffer-even-if-you-do-not-pass-it-one)).

Your problem with the larger scanner buffer is a result of the fact that 
the scanner always reads the longest line into its buffer, even 
if it is longer than the default 1024 bytes. The removing of all `\n`
in your file made the scanner think there is only one really long line, 
which it has to buffer.

As you can see [here](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly), the buffer size has nearly no effect on efficiency 
when you are reading files.

Hope I could help you